# Add multiple object examples for multipart/form-data in Swagger docs

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I hava a POST API using multipart/form-data to send data (requestBody including a binary file, string and object data).

I want to add more than one example for object parameter, but I found using enum is not working:

[image]

here is my swagger docs:

```
    post:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: xxx
      description: xxx
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/User4'
```

```
    User4:
      type: object
      properties:
        thisIsAString:
          type: string
          default: 'testStr'
          enum: 
          - testStr
          - testStr2
        thisIsAObj:
          type: object
          default: obj1
          enum: 
          - obj1: 
            oneOfEx: 'bbb'
          - obj2:
            oneOfEx2: 'aaa'
        file:
          type: string
          format: binary
```

What I want is make the eample of thisIsAObj parameter can be changed by a Drop-down list.

Or can I separate the binary file and object data like this?

[image]

Thank you.